# How to install XCode on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, xcode

I've recently installed Mountain Lion 10.8.2. The installation is successful and had sound and network working out of the box. Now I wanted to install XCode for class and App Store says that I should update to 10.8.5 to install it. How can I install XCode without an update? I don't want to download large updates since my internet is highly charged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XCode 5 requires 10.8.4 as a minimum.

If you have a Apple developer account, you could try to [download](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) an older version (XCode 4.6.3 should work in 10.7 or 10.8).

However, XCode 4.6.3 is still a hefty download (1.81 GB). It may be cheaper for you to download & install OSX 10.8.5 rather than XCode 4.6.3 - especially if you've already downloaded XCode 5...